# Orlov's result on algebraic dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I want to know about the result of Orlov i.e., $D^b(X)≅D^b(X′)\Longrightarrow a(X)=a(X′) $.

Which paper does this result appear in?

Comment: Welcome on MSE; can you write down some detail about your notations, notaions and company? ;)

Comment: Thank you. I think that $X, X'$ are compact complex manifolds and $a(X)$ is algebraic dimension of $X$.

Comment: and I think that $D^b(X)$ is derived bounded category of coherent sheaves on $X$.

Comment: Did you look in "Fourier-Mukai transform in algebraic geometry" ? There are probably references when the result is stated.

Comment: Thank you. I will check.